# How to match key inside an array of object in Mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

A document contains an array of object each object contains a key i want to find all the object that matches the key in mongoose.
Below is the sample schema:

```
const TalentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
  dev_task: [
        {
          development_training: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'TrainingModule',
          },
          developlink: String,
        },
      ],  
})
```

I want to match the document that have development_training to given Id.
How can i do that ?

Update :
Sample Data

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "dev_task": [
      {
        "development_training": 1,
        "developlink": ""
      },
      {
        "development_training": 2,
        "developlink": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "dev_task": [
      {
        "development_training": 1,
        "developlink": ""
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

It should return This : -

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "dev_task": [
      {
        "developlink": "",
        "development_training": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "dev_task": [
      {
        "developlink": "",
        "development_training": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4XNQ5i_DJDr) ?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Your are welcome, also I've posted an answer explaining it in case it is useful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained into [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation), mongo uses dot notation.

> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array **and to access the fields of an embedded document**.

And this is exactly we want.

So to access your document you need to do `dev_task.development_training` into find query in this way:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "dev_task.development_training": 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4XNQ5i_DJDr)

Note that using mongoose is the same query:

```js
yourModel.findOne({"dev_task.development_training": yourId}).then(result => {/*...*/})
```

Comment: Hey J.F i have a doubt. This query returns all the object that have at least one object with "dev_task.development_training": 1 also it returns the array  that have two object with different dev.task.development_training. Please check my question i just updated!